# EditText is not showing text while in the loop like chatGPT

Tags: android, networking, android-edittext, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I want to display the text to edittext while fetching data, but this is only showing the data in the end.

Here is the code

```
    void networkcall(String query) {
    messageList.add(new MessageModel(query, 1));
    messageList.add(new MessageModel("Typing...", 3));
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(messageList.size() - 1);
    OpenAiService service = new OpenAiService(API_KEY);

    List<ChatMessage> message = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
    message.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.USER.value(), query));

    ChatCompletionRequest chatCompletionRequest;

    chatCompletionRequest = ChatCompletionRequest
            .builder()
            .model("gpt-3.5-turbo")
            .messages(message)
            .n(1)
            .maxTokens(500)
            .logitBias(Collections.emptyMap())
            .build();

    Flowable<ChatCompletionChunk> flowableResult = service.streamChatCompletion(chatCompletionRequest);
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    flowableResult.subscribe(chunk -> {
        chunk.getChoices().forEach(choice -> {
            String result = choice.getMessage().getContent();
            if (result != null) {
                buffer.append(result);
                Log.d("Gdfgrd", result);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        editQuery.setText(buffer);

                    }
                });

                Log.d("Gdfgrd", result);


            }

        });
    });

    message.add(new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.SYSTEM.value(), buffer.toString()));

}
```

I was expecting the buffer to be displayed in the `EditText` like ChatGPT.